# How do you make Tkinter GUI output text from print statement?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get my code to display text from a print statement onto the Tkinter GUI - does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please look at some basic `tkinter` tutorials. Also you only ask about replacing the `print` statements. Does that mean that you are going to leave the `input` statements? That can cause a lot of problems

Comment: @TheLizzard - thanks for commenting. What do you mean by input statements? I'm basically building a HTML Parser using the Python Standard Library and need to display the extracted HTML on a Tkinter GUI which is my main difficulty as it currently prints in the CLI. Thanks.

Comment: Do you wish to allow the user to edit the contents of the GUI text box?

Comment: @TheLizzard - no it should be static. Thanks for answering below though I think that helps me a lot. I would give you an upvote but I can't seem to at the moment as I need 15 reputation points!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# This function acts just like the `print` function:
def print_on_gui(*args, sep=" ", end="\n"):
    text = sep.join(map(str, args)) + end
    # Set the Text widget's state to normal so that we can edit its text
    text_widget.config(state="normal")
    # Insert the text at the end
    text_widget.insert("end", text)
    # Set the Text widget's state to disabled to disallow the user changing the text
    text_widget.config(state="disabled")

# Create a new tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a new `Text` widget
text_widget = tk.Text(root, state="disabled")
# Show the widget on the screen
text_widget.pack(fill="both", expand=True)


# Your code should go here
print_on_gui("Hello world!")
print_on_gui("Hello", "world!")


# Go inside tkinter's mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

The problem with this approach is that if your program runs for too long, it can make the window unresponsive. To avoid that you can use threading but that will complicate things a lot more. If you want to, I can write a solution that uses threading.